# Regexp: is it possible to search for string 'string' but not 'string({'

Tags: regex, match

I am trying to find out all occurences of my concrete word (method call with deprecated API) in all files in a directory. I need a regexp to find all such occurences which do not contain updated call (new API). Can you help me please?

Example:

- deprecated api: method(a,b,c)
- new api: method({a:a, b:b, c:c})

The regexp should find all files containing 'method' but not 'method({'.

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `method([^{]`? Or `method\s*(\s*[^{]` if you want to allow whitespace. Also, I suggest to check out the tutorial at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - every programmer should know basic regular expressions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the proper way is to use the negative look-ahead operator, `?!`

```
/method(?!\(\{)/
```

The above states, "any occurence of `method` that is *not* followed by `({`"

It meets your requirements better than the suggested `/method([^{]/` as the latter does not match string end (i.e. `abc abc method`) and it doesn't handle the combination of two characters `({` that you requested very well.

Comment: correct; my version only matches `method(` and not `method`; that's what I *think* the OP wants, but the question is a little ambiguous. If we're specifically looking for function calls, most languages require the `(`, so including it will catch function calls and not (for instance) comments that contain the word `method`

Comment: And, to make sure that we're not thrown off by whitespace, you might use `/method(?!\s*\(\s*\{)/`.

Comment: I'm curious about `doesn't handle the combination of the two characters` though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @James: yeah, i couldn't find a good way to phrase it, but i was referring to what you mentioned in your previous comment, that it matches `method(` not followed by `{` rather than `method` not followed by `({`, if the regex really did need to find all occurences of `method` that aren't `method({`, then assuming `method(` would miss out all potential other occurences, `method_`

Answer (score 2):

```
betelgeuse:tmp james$ echo " method(a,b,c) "> test1
betelgeuse:tmp james$ echo " method(a,b,c) " > test3
betelgeuse:tmp james$ echo " method({a:a, b:b, c:c})" > test2
betelgeuse:tmp james$ grep "method([^{]" test*
test1: method(a,b,c) 
test3: method(a,b,c)
```

To explain: `[ ]` defines a character class - ie, the character in this position can match anything inside the class.

The `^` as the first character of the class is a negation: it means that this class matches any character *except* the characters defined in this class.

The `{` of course is the only character we care about not matching in this case.

So in some, this will match any string that has the characters `method(` followed by any character *except* `{`.

There are other ways you could do this instead:

```
betelgeuse:tmp james$ grep "method(\w" test*
test1: method(a,b,c) 
test3: method(a,b,c)
```

`\w` in this case is (assuming the C locale) equivalent to `[0-9A-Za-z]`. If you want to allow an optional space, you could try:

```
betelgeuse:tmp james$ grep "method([[:alnum:][:space:]]" test*
test1: method(a,b,c) 
test3: method( a, b, c) 
betelgeuse:tmp james$
```

(in grep syntax, `[:alnum:] is the same as`\w`;`[:space:]`refers to any whitespace character - this is represented as`\s` in most regex implementations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [character classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes) to exclude a *following* `{`, e.g.

```
/method\([^{]/
```

Comment: besides what i've commented in my own reply, the `(` needs to be escaped in your regex.